# Are there relevant resources on the Moon for civil engineering?

Tags: the-moon, colonization, materials, natural-resources

We can read about Moon exploitation and making bases on there for long-term colonies. But bringing materials to make buildings there does not makes economical sense, and a large spaceship may be a hard bet. It seems to make much more sense to make buildings out of local resources.

Are there enough resources on the Moon to make a concrete-like building to host operations?

I wonder what kind of materials could be used to make walls and floors and ceilings. On Earth, we use basically sand, water, etc.

Comment: There's two kinds of people: those who build houses and those who dig caves. You can dig.

Comment: Yes, good point. On Earth, digging seems to increase costs. Perhaps the calculation is different on a place like the Moon?

Comment: You need protection from cosmic rays. Digging improves the degree of protection.

Comment: Carbon seems to be missing in quantities needed to make hardened steel. Also see [Is current state-of-the-art additive manufacturing (aka 3D printing) good enough to build parts out of Moon/Mars dust?](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/3890/49)

Comment: [Lunarcrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunarcrete) made from lunar [regolith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regolith).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paul Spudis notes the moon has lots of aggregate. Lunar regolith is shattered bedrock with granules of all different sizes.

Spudis suggests "Instead of water-set lime-based cement, we can use glass to cement particulate material together.  Regolith can be sintered into bricks and blocks, as well as roads and landing pads, using thermal energy (passive solar, concentrated by focusing mirrors) or microwaves that can melt grain edges into a hard, durable ceramic."

See [Regolith, the "Other" Lunar Resource](http://www.airspacemag.com/daily-planet/regolith-the-other-lunar-resource-156943194/)