# What series of devices would you need to deliver to the Martian surface to manufacture concrete entirely in-situ?

Tags: mars, colonization

It seems like you at least need the following:

1. A self-drilling wellhead to reach the subsurface water, storage tank
2. Some process for refining the regolith into the optimal composition, storage tank
3. A mechanism for composing the concrete into a structure.

To support all three, you need #4, a power source. I'm guessing probably an RTG. What I'm asking about here mostly is #2 - I don't know beans about concrete on either planet - what would be the process of collecting and processing that material, and what else have I overlooked here?

Comment: You need a pressure vessel, because the atmospheric pressure on Mars is just at or slightly below the triple point of water, so you're going to have a hard time maintaining liquid water with which to mix the concrete unless you can increase the ambient pressure.

Comment: Other energy producing options might be solar concentrator with turbine or Sterling engine

Answer (score 3):

Concrete is composed of Portland cement, water, and aggregate.

The manufacture of Portland cement is an energy and space intensive process.  To wit:

> The most common way to manufacture portland cement is through a dry method. The first step is to quarry the principal raw materials,
>   mainly limestone, clay, and other materials. After quarrying the rock
>   is crushed. This involves several stages. The first crushing reduces
>   the rock to a maximum size of about 6 inches. The rock then goes to
>   secondary crushers or hammer mills for reduction to about 3 inches or
>   smaller.
>
> The crushed rock is combined with other ingredients such as iron ore or fly ash and ground, mixed, and fed to a cement kiln.
>
> The cement kiln heats all the ingredients to about 2,700 degrees Fahrenheit in huge cylindrical steel rotary kilns lined with special
>   firebrick. Kilns are frequently as much as 12 feet in diameter—large
>   enough to accommodate an automobile and longer in many instances than
>   the height of a 40-story building. The large kilns are mounted with
>   the axis inclined slightly from the horizontal.
>
> The finely ground raw material or the slurry is fed into the higher
>   end. At the lower end is a roaring blast of flame, produced by
>   precisely controlled burning of powdered coal, oil, alternative fuels,
>   or gas under forced draft.
>
> As the material moves through the kiln, certain elements are driven
>   off in the form of gases. The remaining elements unite to form a new
>   substance called clinker. Clinker comes out of the kiln as grey balls,
>   about the size of marbles.
>
> Clinker is discharged red-hot from the lower end of the kiln and
>   generally is brought down to handling temperature in various types of
>   coolers. The heated air from the coolers is returned to the kilns, a
>   process that saves fuel and increases burning efficiency.
>
> After the clinker is cooled, cement plants grind it and mix it with
>   small amounts of gypsum and limestone. Cement is so fine that 1 pound
>   of cement contains 150 billion grains.  The cement is now ready for
>   transport to ready-mix concrete companies to be used in a variety of
>   construction projects.

from [here](http://www.cement.org/cement-concrete-basics/how-cement-is-made)

It seems unlikely that limestone and clay are available on Mars, not to mention the huge facilities.

Probably best to come up with a different substance to build your colony out of.

Note: experiments have been done on making cement from lunar soil simulants. The process of producing the cement is [apparently the same though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunarcrete), although it has only been carried out on a tiny scale.

Comment: He probably doesn't literally mean *concrete* but marscrete, which does not have the same ingredients. I think we were supposed to pick up that it wasn't literal concrete from the context.

Comment: Interesting stuff, but what you're overlooking is WHY those kilns and facilities are so large - economies of scale. I suspect that you could have a pizza-oven sized kiln, as long as you're willing to accept that your output is going to be a small fraction of what a proper Earth facility produces. @called2voyage is right, but this is still good stuff.